# requirements.txt is not considering wild character *

Tags: python-2.7, setup.py

I have a custom python package built using setup.py with the version like `2.0.1, 2.0.2` etc and stored it in artifactory.

Now in my `requirements.txt` If I add like this:

```
custom-package==2.0.2
```

It works perfectly fine. It fetches the right version from artifactory and installs it and continues my process.

but if I change it to like this:

```
custom-package==2.*
```

Then it finds the latest custom-package version which is in my case `2.0.2` from artifactory and installs it. But at the same time it shows the version installation is `0.0.0` not `2.0.2` like this in my log files:

```
Collecting custom-package==2.*
Downloading https://swfactory.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/app/custom-package/master/custom-package-2.0.2.tar.gz (77 kB)
WARNING: Requested custom-package==2.* from https://swfactory.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/app/custom-package/master/custom-package-2.0.2.tar.gz#md5=0bfccc319d9b8108540b75d28980482d (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)), but installing version 0.0.0
```

and if I do pip `pip freeze | grep "custom-package"` --> it gives me `0.0.0` not `2.0.2`
what should I make the change so that it will reflect the right version for my custom-package?

My settings for setup.py

```
def version():
    if os.getenv('BRANCH') == "NON_MASTER":
        __version__ = os.getenv('VERSION')
    else:
        __version__ = os.getenv('VERSION')

    return __version__

setup(
    name="custom_package",
    version=version(),
    ......
    ......
```

Comment: How come both branches contain the same code? Is that a copy/paste issue?

Comment: no, based on the branch version number passed as a parameter to setup.py

Comment: This does not clarify anything. Whether or not `BRANCH == NON_MASTER`, `__version_` is always set to the value of the environment variable `VERSION`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to call `version()` in `setup` and version is set based on the Branch let's say branch in NON-MASTER then the version will be passed as N.N.N.DDMMYYYY.BUILDID at the same time if the branch is MASTER then the version will be passed as N.N.N . this setup.py is called from git pipeline.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Your code does not make sense to me. Also see my answer. I highly doubt any of this can give any meaningful result. Any question about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

That `setup.py` can not possibly work.

Figuring out the version number should not depend on the external environment. It should either be static or depend exclusively on things contained in the *sdist* itself (example reading a `version.txt` file contained in the *sdist*).

What I believe happens here is that when *pip* builds the *sdist*, it does so in an isolated environment, and if I am not mistaken this isolation does not let the environment variables go through (except maybe a selected few, like `PIP_*`). That would be my guess. Anyway, even if *pip*'s build isolation does not suppress the environment variables, there is no control over the environment on a different machine. If I were to install it on my machine, what would the values of the environment variables `BRANCH` and `VERSION` be?

I am not sure how it ends being `0.0.0` specifically though, maybe that is the default value that is used instead of the empty string.